# How to know which Lambda sent a message to the Dead Letter Queue?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I'm using a SNS Topic as a Dead Letter Queue to handle errors thrown by multiple Lambdas. In the error messages, there are the following attributes :

- RequestID,
- ErrorCode,
- ErrorMessage,

However, I can't easily find which Lambda threw the error, since nothing related to it appear in the message (eg: ARN, function name...)

Although it's possible to look up the request ID on CloudWatch, or to create multiple topics, there should be a much easier way to find which Lambda threw the error. Below is the structure of the received message:

```
{
    "Records": [
        {
            "EventSource": "aws:sns",
            "EventVersion": "1.0",
            "EventSubscriptionArn": "",
            "Sns": {
                "Type": "Notification",
                "MessageId": "",
                "TopicArn": "",
                "Subject": null,
                "Message": "",
                "Timestamp": "",
                "SignatureVersion": "",
                "Signature": "",
                "SigningCertUrl": "",
                "UnsubscribeUrl": "",
                "MessageAttributes": {
                    "RequestID": {
                        "Type": "String",
                        "Value": ""
                    },
                    "ErrorCode": {
                        "Type": "String",
                        "Value": "200"
                    },
                    "ErrorMessage": {
                        "Type": "String",
                        "Value": "test"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there any way to add information, such as the ARN, on the Lambda which triggered this error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up configuring:

- One unique SNS topic for every lambda DLQ.
- A lambda listening to the above topic and storing the request ID in S3
- A trail on CloudTrail logging every lambda invoke
- A lambda matching the failed request ID in S3 and the cloudtrail logs. The latter provide the name of the failed lambda.

This infrastructure might seem a bit complicated but it's working very well. It allows to only add one unique `onError: ...` line of code in every lambda configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you figured out a solution or not, but i solved a somewhat similar problem with a little help from boto3.

To give some more context about my setup:

1. I had 2 lambda functions (**lambdaA** and **lambdaB**) listening to a SNS topic which gets updated by S3 object creation events.
2. Both lambda functions use one SNS topic as DLQ which is subscribed by a single dlq lambda (**lambdaDLQ**).

In the **lambdaDLQ's** received message, you get a `Message` attribute which has the message received by the error throwing lambda functions (**lambdaA** or **lambdaB**) which contains the information about SNS message received by them.

So the steps i used to figure out the error throwing lambda function were:

1. Parse the `Message` attribute from **lambdaDLQ**'s event into json.
2. Get the `EventSubscriptionArn` from the above parsed message. This holds the subscription details of the error throwing lambda.
3. Using boto3 to get Protocol, Endpoint, etc. Which give the name of the error throwing lambda.

```
    sns_client = boto3.client('sns')
    arn = 'arn_goes_here'
    response = sns_client.get_subscription_attributes(SubscriptionArn=arn)
```

In case your error throwing lambda functions do not listen to a SNS topic, you might need to change this a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AWS CloudTrail to identify which Lambda executed:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/logging-using-cloudtrail.html

Comment: Thanks for replying! I took a look at how cloudtrail works. IMHO, it is quite limited:
- It stores every call (I only need errors)
- I need to do fetch files in S3 and do a lookup on request ID

It's quite surprising that there doesn't exist a more immediate way to find which lambda threw the error ?

Answer (score 0):

You should have one DLQ per Lambda function. This will let you know where the dead letter is coming from.

Comment: That would require to create one topic per lambda, which I prefer not to do for the sake of scalability.